# ASP.net web api1 sends back this error 500 { "$id": "1", "message": "An error has occurred." }" for a post request with RAW json

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, http-post, iis-7.5

I have a application where I send custom mails. One has to POST the mail details using raw json to a endpoint.

```
{
    "toEmailAddress": "example@exDomain.com",
    "subject": "testsubject",
    "body": "testmessage"
}
```

When I publish it to my local machine (endpoint: http://20ex14566.example.corp/tuportal/api/EmailActions/Mailer) it works fine and sends 200 ok.

However when I publish it to a server keeping all the parameters same I get this:

```
500 Internal Server Error
{
    "$id": "1",
    "message": "An error has occurred."
}
```

Why is it throwing this only when it's published to the server?
But for GET request am able to retrieve the data. The same build I copy from my local to my server. The same happens.

The only header used is `Content-Type:application/json.`

Comment: MR B. how do i make them express themselves? you know anybody here who is an expert and can help? am in the office and my manager is hitting my head to get this job done. but am just stuck.